# Midpoint between 2 coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to calculate the midpoint between 2 coordinates that are located a few meters from each other so it is not relevant the curvature of the earth. I am using the method below that should work:

```
def compute_midPoint(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2):  
  return ((lat1 + lat2)/2, (lon2 + lon2)/2)
```

However the result is not accurate. Doing same operation manually I get the correct result. The difference in results is slightly different, would you know what I am missing?

Example:

```
compute_midPoint(53.2604111, -2.1279681, 53.2600830, -2.1271415)
```

```
Python result: 53.260247050000004, -2.1271415 X

MANUAL TESTING √
1065204941/2 = 53.2602470
42551096/2 = -2.1275548
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your longitude calculation is wrong, `(lon2 + lon2)/2` - that works out to be just `lon2`.

It needs to be `(lon1 + lon2)/2` instead. The latitude is close enough, though you may want to restrict the number of decimals when printing it out. You can limit it to seven decimal places with an f-string like `f"{123.4567890123456789:.7f}"` which will give you the string `123.4567890`.

Answer (score 1):

From python documentation:

"Floating-point numbers are represented in computer hardware as base 2 (binary) fractions. For example, the decimal fraction

Unfortunately, most decimal fractions cannot be represented exactly as binary fractions. A consequence is that, in general, the decimal floating-point numbers you enter are only approximated by the binary floating-point numbers actually stored in the machine."

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html